# What MySQL collation is best for accepting all unicode characters?

Tags: mysql, collation

Our column is currently collated to `latin1_swedish_ci` and special unicode characters are, obviously, getting stripped out. We want to be able to accept chars such as `U+272A ✪`, `U+2764 ❤`, (see [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)) etc. I'm leaning towards `utf8_unicode_ci`, would this collation handle these and other characters? I don't care about speed as this column isn't an index.

MySQL Version: 5.5.28-1

Comment: Mathias posts on here but I happen to just be here and have this bookmarked: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The *collation* is the least of your worries, what you need to think about is the *character set* for the column/table/database. The collation (rules governing how data is *compared* and *sorted*) is just a corollary of that.

MySQL supports several Unicode character sets, `utf8` and `utf8mb4` being the most interesting. `utf8` supports Unicode characters in the [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), i.e. a subset of all of Unicode. `utf8mb4`, available since MySQL 5.5.3, supports *all* of Unicode.

The *collation* to be used with any of the Unicode encodings is most likely `xxx_general_ci` or `xxx_unicode_ci`. The former is a general sorting and comparison algorithm independent of language, the latter is a *more complete* language independent algorithm supporting more Unicode features (e.g. treating "ß" and "ss" as equivalent), but is therefore also slower.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html.

Comment: I ran this query: `ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable CHANGE mycolumn mycolumn VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;` and I'm still not getting the correct values, do I have to set the table and database charsets as well?

Comment: No, only columns have charsets, table and database charsets are only default settings if not otherwise specified per column. What does that mean, "you don't get the correct values"? How are you trying to get the correct values? You need to set the correct connection charset front to back, including the client connection which also needs to be set to `utf8mb4`. See [this article](http://kunststube.net/frontback) for in-depth instructions.

Comment: A Java application is updating the DB, and instead of special unicode characters I'm just seeing a `?` in their place. I don't develop the Java application, I'm guessing it must be escaping the characters itself.

Comment: That's terrifically vague. :) As laid out in the beforelinked article, encodings must be handled correctly front to back to preserve characters correctly. The problem could be anywhere in the chain *(web?) <-> Java <-> DB driver <-> DB*. If you're not responsible for the Java app, just make sure the database saves and returns data in the correct encoding.

Comment: I will relay this to the Java developer and see if that solves the problem. I'll give you the bounty though (in 4 hours, when I can award it), thanks for the help!

Comment: Not quite the same, but I figured I would mention this if anybody is using Javascript: I had a problem where a Javascript function was calling ``escape()`` on my strings, prior to handing them off to a PHP script that inserted them into the DB. This caused the strings to be encoded in such a way that accented chars showed up in the DB as, say, u0219. Once I changed ``escape()`` to ``encodeURI()``, the data got passed to the DB correctly.