# Better collation option to support all languages in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, collation

What is the best collation in MYSQL that I need to use to support all languages in Varchar datatype?

Thanks,

Comment: There is no "best" there's only a lowest-common denominator. Sorting and comparison rules vary wildly by language. The order of the alphabet is far from constant.

Comment: also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were starting a project today with MySQL 8.0, I'd choose this as a default:

character set: **utf8mb4**

collation: **utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci**

(reportedly this collation does not work for Canadian French)

See also: https://www.percona.com/live/e17/sites/default/files/slides/Collations%20in%20MySQL%208.0.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As character set  `utf8mb4` is "safest", as it also supports 4-byte Unicode, where `utf8` only goes up to 3 bytes.

The collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` includes all Unicode characters and has some "smart" comparison matching.

Comment: That addresses the question of "best character set", not "best collation".

Comment: sorry, that's right. `utf8_general_ci` covers all unicode and always worked for me. also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329314/what-mysql-collation-is-best-for-accepting-all-unicode-characters

Comment: .. but in fact it should be `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` or `utf8mb4_general_ci`

Comment: correct - our comments overlapped ;)  I've updated the answer

Comment: `_unicode_` comes from Unicode version 4.0, many years old. ` _general_` does not take into account multi-character comparisions, such as non-spacing accents.

Comment: `_unicode_520_` includes improvements in Unicode 5.20.  `_0900_` reflects Unicode 9.0.  Some of the differences can be seen in  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html

Comment: Your answer applies through MySQL 5.7; Bill's applies to 8.0 (so far).