# Laravel save Arabic into MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, laravel, arabic-support

[image]

I am building an application using Laravel framework. In the application there are two sets of language English and Arabic. When saving Arabic language field Name and Address data into MYSQL database. it saves the Arabic language in corrupted format.

name : ÙÙÙÙ

What is that I am missing error

Comment: use utf8 (or utf16 ....extra) collation for your database

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14371188/10573560

Comment: I did not get. If I change collation of the database.will it be effecting to all the columns of all the tables

Comment: every table has its collation, by default, it took it from db collation, you should make sure of changing the collation of your db and all your tables, I use this collation for arabic charset

Comment: Do it for single column, like : arabic for windows `$table->string('name')->collation('cp1256_general_ci');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

You should use unicode set of collation **utf8_unicode_ci** or **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** so it will support some specific languages chars.

probably **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** since it's the default for laravel.

more info and explanation about collation and the differences please check

[What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)